# $scope.statusMessage is undefined

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module("MainLogin.controller", [])

// ========= Controllers
.controller("LogInController", function($scope) {



})

.controller("CreateAccountController", function ($scope, $rootScope, createAccountService) {
        $rootScope.statusMessage = null;

        $scope.ActionCreateAccount = function () {
        $scope.statusMessage = createAccountService.createAccount($scope.createAccount);
        console.log($scope.statusMessage);
    }
})
// <======== Controllers

// ========= Factories
.factory("createAccountService",["$http", function($http, $scope) {
    var fac = {};

    fac.createAccount = function (accountDetail) {
        return $http({
            url: '/Account/CreateAccount',
            data: { account: accountDetail },
            method: 'post'
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            debugger;
            if (response.data.status == "1") {
                $scope.statusMessage = "Successfully created the account"
                alert($scope.statusMessage);
            } else {
                $scope.statusMessage = response.data.status
                alert($scope.statusMessage);
            }
        })
    }


    return fac;
}])
```

`Cannot read property 'statusMessage' of undefined"` is the error I get even when I change the `$rootScope` to `$scope`. I just want to set the $scope.statusMessage to whatever is the result of the factory so I can bind it to my html. Can you please point to me where I get it wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your service to:

```
.factory("createAccountService",["$http", function($http, $scope) {
   var fac = {};

   fac.createAccount = function (accountDetail) {
      return $http({
        url: '/Account/CreateAccount',
        data: { account: accountDetail },
        method: 'post'
      });
   }
   return fac;
 }])
```

And your controller to:

```
.controller("CreateAccountController", function ($scope, $rootScope, createAccountService) {
    $scope.statusMessage = null;

    $scope.ActionCreateAccount = function () {
      createAccountService.createAccount($scope.createAccount)
        .then(function(response){
          if (response.data.status == "1") {
              $scope.statusMessage = "Successfully created the account"
              alert($scope.statusMessage);
          } else {
              $scope.statusMessage = response.data.status
              alert($scope.statusMessage);
          }
        console.log($scope.statusMessage);
    });
}})
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. How come I can alert the response.data.status in the factory but I cannot pass it?